# Is it possible to call fireEvent with a buffer in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I have a button that, when clicked, fire the event. The problem is that if I press it 2-5 times, the event will be fired the same number of times.

I tried a few options:

```
buttonHendler: function() {
 this.fireEvent('myEvent',param,callback,2000)
}

buttonHendler: function() {
 Ext.Function.createBuffered(this.fireEvent('myEvent',param,callback), 2000, this)
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
I would be grateful for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

We suspend the button events while doing whatever the button was supposed to do then restart resume the events.  Extra bonus to add a spinner icon.

```
// can be in a singleton class or add to your own button or whereever.
addButtonProcessing: function(button) {
    button.prevIconCls = button.getIconCls();
    button.prevText = button.getText();
    button.setIconCls('x-fa fa-spin fa-sync');
    button.suspendEvents(); // To prevent double click
},

removeButtonProcessing: function(button) {
    button.setIconCls(button.prevIconCls);
    button.setText(button.prevText);
    button.removeCls('x-pressing');
    button.resumeEvents();
},
```

So in button handler:

```
// if the methods are in the viewport controller.    
Ext.Viewport.getController().addButtonProcessing(button);
// do something
Ext.Viewport.getController().removeButtonProcessing(button);
```